# Keycloak Server not sending the custom email verification URL

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect, keycloak-gatekeeper, keycloak-nodejs-connect

I am trying to integrate custom email verification flow using keycloak server version 21.1.1. I am using following REST API `/admin/realms/**{Realm}**/users/**{UserId}**/execute-actions-email?client_id=**{Client}**&lifespan=3600&action=UPDATE_PASSWORD&redirect_uri=https://example.com/createpassword`

The issue I am facing is that the email verification link received to the user through email doesn't redirect the user to the redirect_uri provided in the request.

It sends user to the keycloak instance which is not accessible in our case as it was behind the private network with restricted access.

All I need is to customise the email verification link so that I can direct the user to my REST API which will then communicate with the Keycloak instance to complete the reset password flow.